# How can I add a news website that does not have rss feed, to Calibre?

Tags: calibre

Some of the news websites do not have an rss feed. Is there a way to add such websites to Calibre as a news source?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service like [FetchRSS](http://fetchrss.com/) to create a feed from the news site. It'll give you a feed URL to add to Calibre.